# i want to do some functions with button. i want when i click on button it will be show result. result comes from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

i'm new in PHP i don't know howto use this function...output is a button but when i click on button function not run. i want to get data from database.

```
<?php include('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit']))  {

$sql = "SELECT book_name from books";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "book name: " . $row["book_name"]. "<br>";


   }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
}
$conn->close();
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="check.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="btn">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `isset($_POST['submit'])` by `isset($_POST['btn'])`.

When you submit your form, you send all the input name with `$_POST` method.

Here you have only ONE input with `name = 'btn'`.

I do this test :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn']))  {
    echo 'IT WORKS !';
}
?>
```

And it works for me, after clicking on "Valider" I got my `echo` :

[image]

Here is an example of how you can try to do it using jQuery and Ajax. I tried to explain how it works and made an example that edit your book list without reloading the page on submit. Hope it helps !

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // When the form with id 'get_book_list' is sumbit, I will do something :
  $("#get_book_list").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    
    // This is how an ajax call looks like (one example) :
    // $.ajax({
    //     type: "POST", // the method you will use to send the data
    //     url: "yourfile.php", // the php file you want to call
    //     data : /* the data you want to send in your php file */,
    //     dataType: "json", // the data type you want to receive from the php file
    //     success: function(response){
    //         // Do something if the ajax call works : here you will edit your book list
    //         // 'response' is what the php will return, here imagine it's a JSON (dataType = 'json')
    //     },
    //     error: function(x,e,t){
    //         // Do something if the ajax call return error
    //     }
    // });
    
    //I will do the same but without the Ajax :
    // 1/ Imagine you are in the success part of the ajax call
    // 2/ This is the "response" you get from the php after the select :
    
    var response = [{"book_name" : "title1"}, {"book_name" : "title2"}, {"book_name" : "title3"}];
    
    // 3/ Now just edit your book_list to get what you want :
    
    // I will build a list with each title
    var book_list = "<ul>";
    $.each(response, function(key, book) {
      book_list += "<li>"+book.book_name+"</li>";
    });
    book_list += "</ul>";
    
    // I add my list in my div
    $('.book-list').html(book_list);
  
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div class="book-list">
  <!-- here you will update the list of book -->
  </div>
  
  <form action="" method="post" id="get_book_list">
      <input type="submit" name="btn">
  </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: its work but before clicking mean when i refresh page it will appear without clicking

Comment: When you submit a form you will reload your page. If you don't want to reload, you should try Ajax maybe? Can you use jQuery?

Comment: i will try to use but i have no idea

Comment: The idea with Ajax is : 1/ You have a form in page.html. 2/ On click / submit (a trigger), you will send some data to a file.php : you make your request to get the list of books, then you will send back this data to your Ajax call. 3/ In the Ajax call, you have a "success part" (if it works) when you can get those data. Now you will just have to get the list of book and use jQuery to edit your page WITHOUT reloading it :) Is it clear enough?

Comment: I add an example if it can helps you

Comment: its looks good! .... you know that i'm beginner in this lang, i have a idea in my mind, i want to make a program of book system mean that there are two person to interact with program 1 Admin and 2 student ..admin will add books in system(database) and student will takes books ..i want to show books details to student ..student will take books and save books ... part admin is complete ..the problem is student..    can you give some ideas? i hope you will understand my problem...i don'n know how to show books onclick of student..

Comment: @AtifRaja Well, Ajax is good for you if you want to load new content without reloading the page. For example, for the student part : you give student a list of book, and when student click on one you open a modal : the content of this modal will be load using Ajax to give student details (author, resume, etc. depend of what you got in database). For the "take / save books", just add btn for each book and on click you do what you want...can't really help you it depend of what YOU want to do :)

Answer (score 0):

your form actions says "check.php". As a result, when you hit the submit button, you get redirected to check.php page. 
your form should simply be like

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="btn">
</form>
```

when action="", the if part of your php will get executed for your current case

Answer (score 0):

isset($_POST['submit']) is false, you should submit some info. you can add `<input type="text"  name="submit" value="1" />`, lets your form have info.

Comment: Add a input tag of name to submit so that there is a value in POST.